# C# WPF Window.Closed only firing once

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF project I have an event `subWindow.Closed` that basically updates my main window when closed. This event only works on the original `subWindow` so even if I write `this.subWindow = new SubWindow();` it won't fire again if I open and close the sub window again. The easy answer seems to be to cancel the close using `subWindow.Closing` and hide it instead, but I'd like to also make the main window unusable using `subWindow.ShowDialog` if I can, which doesn't work with hiding the sub window.

Right now my code looks something like this:

```
public SubWindow subWindow = new SubWindow();

public MainWindow()
{
  subWindow.Closed += (s, EventArgs) =>
  {
    //main window update code
    subWindow = new SubWindow(); //this lets me ShowDialog but wont get caught by the event handler
  }
}

public void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.subWindow.ShowDialog();
  //setting subWindow here would let me always ShowDialog but the event only triggers once
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all from constructor of `MainWindow` and put all to the `Button.Click` event handler:

```
public void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    subWindow = new SubWindow();
    subWindow.Closed += (s, EventArgs) =>
    {
        //main window update code
    };
    this.subWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```